# Rate limiting in WSO2 is not happening

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, rate-limiting

I am trying to use the throttling functionality of WSO2. I have published on API with few subscription tiers made available for subscribers and added an advanced throttling policy as 5 requests per minute.
After that, I am subscribing to the API through an Application. The application level limit is set to 10 requests per minute and the subscriber is using a subscription tier of 5 requests per minute while subscribing to that API.

Now, I generate a test token with the production key and use it to invoke the API. But, here issue is that I am able to access the API more number of times than the limit I have set. It sometimes gives message for quota exceeded after 13 or 14 requests in a minute and sometimes it doesn't even give a message.

At the same time I am getting an exception at the backend on wso2 server console as below.

```
Exception in thread "pool-39-thread-111" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For in
put string: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.ipToLong(APIUtil.java:5826)

        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.publisher.DataProcessAndPub
        lishingAgent.run(DataProcessAndPublishingAgent.java:149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2016-09-23 12:11:29,355]  INFO - AndesRecoveryTask Running DB sync task.
```

need some help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently this supports only IPv4. I created a bug report. It will be fixed in next version.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5397

So, for now either you'll have to move to IPv4 or fix the error in [this method](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/utils/APIUtil.java#L5822:L5836) yourself and patch the server.